# iPhone app to record 3D location information

Tags: gps, 3d, ios, iphone

Does anyone know of an app that would run on an iPhone or iTouch that would record the X,Y and Z information from an external GPS?

I am using a Dual XGPS150 Bluetooth receiver.  The GPS will record X,Y,Z info, but I am having issues with an app that will record the info, and provide it back to me in a useful format.  I have tried GISRoam, but it will not record the Z information.  I have looked at other apps, but I am not sure if it will record the Z info and allow me to export it into a format that can be used in a GIS solution like QGIS.  Does anyone have any experience with the WolfGIS, Map My Run, or any of the other IOS apps?

Comment: Sports Tracker for i-devices https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sports-tracker/id426684873?mt=8 (have used this for 5 years on Nokia and Android Phone/Tablet) Works very well and records lat/lng and altitude works best with assisted GPS on.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but how do I download my data locally so that I can analyze it in QGIS, or another GIS application?

Comment: SportTracker can export to .csv,.gpx and KML which can be loaded into QGIS natively

Comment: Older version of SportsTracker exporting http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9Iu2DhJTtQ&t=0m26s

Comment: Thanks for that.  The iPhone version is a little different.  I had to export it from the website.  This is ok, but I would like to have offline capabilities.

Comment: ViewRanger might be worth a look but probably similar set up to SportTracker and MapMyRun. You can export a GPX on the device.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that if you had a bluetooth or serial GPS that would connect to an iOS device that the operating system would automatically use those GPS readings instead of the device's internal GPS.  Which means it should work with any app on the device.

I know for sure it works with a serial cable and I've been told it works with an external bluetooth GPS.  It was mentioned in [this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/15/smartphones-tablets-and-gps-accuracy/) by Jeff Shaner .

Comment: Jeff I know that, that isn't my question.  My question was about the apps that will record the GPS information and store it into a format that can be exported to a usable format in a GIS software package.

Answer (score 1):

***Maps n Trax*** can do this.  Records X, Y & Z and can export to shapefiles, GPX, KML, etc.

https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/maps-n-trax-offline-maps-gps/id550937509?mt=8

Its getting a bit long in the tooth and the UI doesn't work as nicely with the current iOS version (freezes for 5-10 seconds sometimes).  But it is quite functional.

(I'm currently building a new iOS GIS which also does this, but it's not released yet.)